# React MUI Switch Styling Randomly Changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Trying to incorporate a switch component from MUI into my code and for some reason, upon initial page load the switch looks like how it should, identical to the one on the MUI site. On reload however, it changes and looks like this:

[Slider Styling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ea8y.jpg)

How do I get it to not change into that? This is what my code looks like in that section:

```
<div
  style={{
    zIndex: 1,
    position: "absolute",
    margin: "25px 0 0 0",
    float: "left",
    left: "22px"
  }}>
  <label>Show Voided Orders:</label>
  <Switch  
  defaultChecked={false} 
  />
  </div>
```

Comment: you can use color property
https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/palette/#adding-new-colors

Answer (score 1):

You can try these methods in the document (https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/how-to-customize/).

example:
https://mui.com/material-ui/react-switch/#customization

CSS class name for reference:
https://mui.com/material-ui/api/switch/#css

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).